# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements-in-app-payments related

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, code-signing

I am getting the following error while validating the app before submitting to App store(using Xcode 6):

> invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature
>   contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS.
>   Specifically, key 'com.apple.developer.in-app-payments’ in
>   'Payload/Appname.app/Appname' is not supported

I got the similar answer for iCloud and associated domains.

Answer (score 1):

Now i have resolved it. Please

1. Create new App-Id with required permissions
2. Create new pem file as pem file bounds with App-Id.
3. Finally create new mobile provision.

Change bundle identifier & mobile provision & validate it. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Same here need fix and Fk Up Apple, why you have to kill Xcode and Developers lives always?